# Splitting concatenated byte arrays back into multiple byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption

I'm encrypting data with Rijndael. I'd like to save the encrypted bytes of the data in my database so I can decrypt it back later.

Problem is if I use a new instance of `RijndaelManaged` for the decrypt function, my key and IV aren't going to be the same and decryption will fail.

So I've use LINQ to concatenate the byte arrays:

```
return encrypted.Concat(key).Concat(iV);
```

As we know this returns an `IEnumerable<byte>`. I've got a bit ahead of myself because I have no idea what to do with this now I've stuck it all together.

I'm not worried about memory usage as its just small bits of text data that I'm encrypting.

I know that my `KeySize` is 256 which means that I *could* split out the key from the IEnumerable, but then I don't actually know where content or IV start/end so this is where I'm tripping up...

Is there a way I can break up this IEnumerable back into the constituent byte arrays that made it in the first place?

Comment: It's just like any other data storage scheme, if you won't always know the lengths of pieces from context then you must store the length along with the data. There are many, many ways to do so, something as simple as prefixing byte sequences with a 4- or 8-byte big-endian integer count of the number of bytes that follow may suffice.

Comment: Key and IV are generally of constant length, therefore switch the order to `key.Concat(iV).Concat(encrypted)`. This way you will know that key always starts at offset 0, IV always starts at offset 256/8=32, and the encrypted data always starts at offset 48 (if the IV is 128 bits long which is usually the case).

Comment: What's the point of encryption if you concatenate the key to the cyphertext?